# ERROR 1070: Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang., > org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Having a problem with casting data to datetime with pig. Importing the following dataset, tab delimited, I added the \t to illustrate.

```
5000001 \t  1133938 \t 1273719 \t 2008-06-01 00:03:35.0
```

I want to take the last value (2008-06-01 00:03:35.0) and extract the month. Loading it as a DateTime produces a blank field. So I want to import it as a chararray and then use toDate to turn it into dateTime field that I can use getMonth on.

when I try in the shell I get this:

```
grunt> orders = load '/home/cloudera/Desktop/orders1' using PigStorage('\t') AS (orderID:int, cusID:int, productId:chararray, time:chararray);
grunt> to_date = FOREACH orders GENERATE toDate(time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') as (dTime:DateTime), cusID;
2017-04-19 01:13:46,206 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1492588751037.log
```

The log file contains this:

> ERROR 1070: Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang.,
> org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>
> Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:  <line 9, column 34>
> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception:
> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
> Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang.,
> org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]    at
> org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:196)
> at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1660)
> at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1633)
> at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:587)   at
> org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
> at
> org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
> at
> org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
> at
> org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
> at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
> org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)    at
> org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:  <line
> 9, column 34> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception:
> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
> Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang.,
> org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]    at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildUDF(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1507)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_eval(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:9372)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.projectable_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:11051)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.var_expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10810)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.expr(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:10159)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.flatten_generated_item(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7488)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.generate_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:17590)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_plan(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15982)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15849)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1933)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
> ... 16 more Caused by:
> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
> Could not resolve toDate using imports: [, java.lang.,
> org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]    at
> org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:653)
> at
> org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.getClassForAlias(PigContext.java:769)
> at
> org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildUDF(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1504)
> ... 29 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pig function names are case-sensitive. It is `ToDate()`.

```
grunt> to_date = FOREACH orders GENERATE ToDate(time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') as (dTime:DateTime), cusID;
```

Comment: Thanks, easy one to miss there